# Name 'rows' not defined for CSV load

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I have this problem in my code where I wanted to convert the dataset into a list but instead get a "row is not defined" error.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("exam_data.csv")
def load_csv(data): 
 dataset = list(data) 
 with open(filename, 'r') as file: 
     csv_reader = reader(file) 
 for row in csv_reader: 
     if not row: 
         continue 
dataset.append(row)
return dataset
```

Comment: It closes the file once you tab out of the with statement. Try indenting everything up to the return.

Comment: ok i will try that.

Comment: Hi so I'm kinda new to StackOverflow and I would like to know what I did wrong with my post and how should I fix the post? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in one line by this

```
list_row = dataset.values.tolist()
```

or you can correct your logical error as suggested by @chris

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("exam_data.csv")
def load_csv(data): 
 dataset = list(data) 
 with open(filename, 'r') as file: 
     csv_reader = reader(file) 
 for row in csv_reader: 
     if not row: 
         continue 
     else:
         dataset.append(row)
return dataset
```